# Simplify $f(y) = \displaystyle \sum^{\lfloor\frac{1}{y} \rfloor}_{x= 1} xy\left(\frac{1-y}{1-(x-1)y}\right)^{x-1}$, where $0 < y < 0.5$

Tags: real-analysis

Kindly simplify $f(y) =  \displaystyle \sum^{\lfloor\frac{1}{y} \rfloor}_{x= 1} xy\left(\frac{1-y}{1-(x-1)y}\right)^{x-1}$, where $0 < y  < 0.5$.

Comment: What does the upper limit on the sum mean when $1/y$ is not an integer? And what does $O(y^y)$ mean in the range of $y$ that is given?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I have edited the question to complete the meaning.

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? You don't expect a closed form, do you?

Comment: @abx I expect a close form if possible. I also tried to calculate this function using WolframAlpha which is showing an exponentially decreasing trend of this function for $y = (0,0.5]$ and then it increases linearly. I am only finding an explanation for $f(y)$, for  $y = (0,0.5]$.

Comment: @abx I edited the question according to the above discussion. Is it can be shown that  $f(y) > 1$ for $y \in (0,5]$.

Comment: Could you add some detail about (1) where this function comes from, (2) what kind of information you want about this function if there is no closed form? e.g. do you want to understand the asymptotics in this range? Certainly if $y> 0.5$ then $\lfloor \frac{1}{y} \rfloor < 2$ so only the $x=1$ term, which is indeed linear in $y$, contributes.

Comment: @WillSawin This function comes in the context of analysis of a randomized algorithm for graph coloring, already published by us in CTW2020.  $y \in (0,1)$ is a probability. $f(y)$ is a positive value. I already told $f(y)$ is linear for $y > 0.5$, but we are interested in low probability, specially their asymptotic behavior.

Comment: "simplify" is too broad to give meaningful answers. Can you pose a more specific question, e.g. "what is the asymptotic behaviour of this sum for $y\rightarrow 0$"?

Answer (score 2):

$$f(y) =  \displaystyle \sum^{\lfloor\frac{1}{y} \rfloor}_{x= 1} xy\left(\frac{1-y}{1-(x-1)y}\right)^{x-1},\;\;0<y<1/2.$$

The nontrivial regime is when $y\rightarrow 0$. Then the sum is dominated by the last term, so we can approximate

$$f(y)\approx y\lfloor\frac{1}{y} \rfloor \left(\frac{1-y}{1+y-y\lfloor\frac{1}{y} \rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor\frac{1}{y} \rfloor-1}.$$

This is actually quite accurate already for $y\lesssim 0.2$, see the plot where the exact result (red) is almost indistinguishable from the approximation (green).

The upper envelope of the zigzag curve (orange) is given by the points where $1/y$ is an integer, so by setting $x=1/y$,
$$f_{\rm upper-envelope}(y)=(1/y-1)^{1/y-1}.$$
The lower envelope (blue) is obtained by setting $x=1/y-1$,
$$f_{\rm lower-envelope}(y)=(2y)^{2-1/y} (1-y)^{1/y-1} .$$

[image]

Comment: Can we estimate $(2y)^{2-1/y} (1-y)^{1/y-1} \leq f(y) \leq \left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{y}-1}$ for $0 < y < 0.5$?

Comment: it's a small-$y$ approximation, accurate in the range $0<y\lesssim 0.2$

Comment: But in your proof statement, you did not use $0< y < 0.2$, the simulation shows that approximation is correct, but can there be any formal proof.  What about $0.5 > y > 0.2$? Why the expression is not holding here. Particularly, what is special about $0.2$.

Comment: I am replacing the sum by the largest term, which is only accurate if $y\ll 1$; there is nothing special about $0.2$, it's just the point where in the graph the red and green curves become indistinguishable; for $y>0.2$ there are at most 5 terms in the sum, so there is not much simplification possible or needed, just keep these 5 terms.